# Cakephp custom query with left join table rows as nested arrays

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to get nested arrays for my Cakephp custom query below:

```
$this->query("
                SELECT *
                FROM group_buys GroupBuy
                LEFT JOIN products Product
                ON Product.id = GroupBuy.product_id
                LEFT JOIN group_buy_users GroupBuysUser
                ON GroupBuysUser.group_buy_id = GroupBuy.id
                LEFT JOIN group_buy_images GroupBuyImage
                ON GroupBuyImage.group_buy_id = GroupBuy.id
                LEFT JOIN product_details ProductDetail
                ON ProductDetail.product_id = Product.id
                LEFT JOIN specifications Specification
                ON Specification.id = ProductDetail.specification_id
                LEFT JOIN specification_categories SpecificationCategory
                ON SpecificationCategory.id = Specification.specification_category_id
                WHERE GroupBuy.id = {$id}
            ");
```

Problem with this is that it comes up with redundant data obviously with GroupBuy table row values repeating which I don't want.

Is there a way we can have nested arrays if LEFT JOINED table has more rows than the former table with Cake's custom query?

I know this can be done with find recursive = 2 but would like to achieve this with custom query.

Comment: With which column would you compare the rows

Comment: Why do you need to use query()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using containable?

```
$this->GroupBuy->Behaviors->attach('Containable');

$this->GroupBuy->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('GroupBuy.id' => $id),
    'contain' => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'ProductDetail' => array(
                'Specification' => array(
                    'SpecificationCategory'
                )
            )
        ),
        'GroupBuysUser',
        'GroupBuyImage'
    ),
));
```

Comment: I know and I've tried but I prefer to use custom query instead as I would like to know exactly what's going on behind the scenes. What query is being outputted with those containable find query?

Comment: It will end up being more than one query, you can see any queries that are run by adding `echo $this->element('sql_dump');` to your layout, you will need debug on.